# routes to non-RESTfull controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-routing

Let's say I have a controller named `HomeController` and I don't intend to use it as a RESTful resource, how can I define routes to this controller in a bulk manner? e.g something like this:

```
controller :home do
  collection do
    get   :dashboard
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
resources :home, only: [] do 
  collection do 
    get 'dashboard'
    get 'another_dashboard'
  end
end
```